# How to fix PostgreSQL Interval Syntax Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

The code below works on my local machine MySQL 8.0 but not on PostgreSQL.

```
DB::raw('sum(CASE WHEN date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN f.amount ELSE 0 END ) as last_month')
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix?

Error:

```
syntax error at or near \"30\"\nLINE 1: ...um(CASE WHEN date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) TH...\n                                                            ^ (SQL:
```

Comment: PostgreSQL intervals should be in quotes i.e. `interval '30 day'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date functions and syntax widely vary across databases. You cannot just port such code from one database to another and expect that it will work as-is.

Postgres wants a literal string as interval description. It also supports the standard `filter` to aggregate and window functions, that can be used to simplify you code as:

```
sum(f.amount) filter(where date >= current_date - interval '30' day) as last_month
```

Of if you want `0` when there is no corresponding row in the group:

```
coalesce(
    sum(f.amount) filter(where date >= current_date - interval '30' day), 
    0
) as last_month
```